# Azure spring boot JPA

Tags: spring, spring-boot, azure, spring-data-jpa

Am using azure keyvault to store my db username , url  & password. I am using

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

this dependency to read the values configured in keyvaults in my spring boot application. But am getting **Failed to determine suitable jdbc url** error when the application loads. Can anyone help me one this

Comment: How are you configuring the data source?

Comment: am using spring data jpa  ,  `<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>`

Comment: and the url is configured in keyvault as **spring-datasource-url**

Comment: `spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets` fetches values from the keyvault and makes them available as properties, but you have to use the properties somewhere. Are you doing that? What's in your application.yml?

Comment: `<dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets</artifactId>
    </dependency>` , yes am using that as well, can you please let me know what you need from the properties file?

Comment: **spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, ${spring-datasource-url}

There could be a possibility that you might have given wrong MS SQL URL, that might be causing to throw the above exception.
you can refer to the [GITHUB](https://github.com/amisham96/Springboot_AzureKeyVault_Fetch_Secret/tree/main) documentation which I have followed.

***I have tried the same from my end and got expected results:***

**Step 1:**

Open the Azure Cloud Shell and run below command to get list of subscriptions
 `az account list`

**Step 2:**

Setting the perticular Subscription
`az account set -s your\_subscription\_id`

**Step 3 :**

Creating service principal
`az ad sp create-for-rbac --name myapp --role Contributor --scopes /subscriptions/mySubscriptionID`

- Go to Active Directory and select service principal app and store below details:

```
Your Client_ID  
Your Client\_Secret\_Value  
Your Tenant_ID
```

**Step 4 :**
Follow Below Steps:

- Create Resource Group in Azure Portal
- Create KeyVault in Azure Portal by selecting resource group
- After Creating Key Vault create secret and store your secret key
- Now select your key vault and in left hand side select option called “Access policies”.

[image]

- Click on **Create** and select the permissions which you want such as “*Get, List, Recover, Set, Delete, Backup, Restore*” in **secret permissions**.

[image]

- Click “***Next***” and select your service principal app you created in “***Step3***” and click “***Create***”.

[image]

**Step 5:**

Now Copy *Your Client_ID, Your Client_Secret_Value, Your Tenant_ID and Key Vault URL* in Spring Boot application Under *resources* folder in *application.properties* file like below:

```java
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-id=Client_ID  
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].credential.client-secret=Client_Secret  
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].endpoint=KeyVault_URL  
spring.cloud.azure.keyvault.secret.property-sources[0].profile.tenant-id=Tenant_ID
```

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Pravallika Kothaveerannagari , application has connected successfully, one more issue is that spring boot 2.7.8 has issue embedded tomcat,  pls refer this  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33974

Answer (score 1):

`spring-cloud-azure-starter-keyvault-secrets` fetches values from the keyvault and makes them available as properties, but you have to use the properties somewhere.

You seem to be missing the basic datasource configuration. Assuming the keyvault contains entries for `spring-datasource-url`, `db-username` and `db-password`, in `application.yml` (or equivalent) you need somethings like:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${spring-datasource-url}
    username: ${db-username}
    password: ${db-password}
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

Comment: thanks @ekalin, i have the config as you have suggested, but still not connecting.

Comment: nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, ${spring-datasource-url}